# How to align Text and TextEditor in SwiftUI (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I found that spacing between `Text` and the line-spacing in a `Text`/`TextEditor` are different.

[image]

Red lines in orange border box are displayed by several `Text` in a `VStack`, while black lines from one `TextEditor`.

And this difference is device-based, which means it performs different on different devices.

I am trying to use `TextEditor`+`Text` in a `ZStack` to achieve code highlighting. The `TextEditor` receives user input but the `.foregroundColor` is set as "Color.clear". The `Text` concatenates the tokens with different colors.

> Given a code in `String`, my model will scanning it and split it into something like `[[Substring]]`, where each `[Substring]` is one line in the original code and each `Substring` is a word in the line, e.g.,`"x=1\ny=x+1"`will be first split into 2 lines `"x=1"` and `"y=x+1"`, then transferred into [["x", "=", "1"], ["y", "=", "x", "+", "1"]].

I have tried to use `reduce` function to concatenate the `Text`.

```
lines.reduce(Text("")) { text, line in text +
    line.reduce(Text("")) { text, word in text + Text(word)
    } + Text("\n")
}
```

it performs well but leads to significant latency when the code become long. (because it need to re-create all the `Text` whenever the user input)

To solve the problem, I switch to `ForEach` in a `VStack`,

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
    ForEach(0..<lines.count, id:\.self){i in
        lines[i].reduce(Text("")) { text, word in text + Text(word)
        }
    }
}
```

The interaction becomes very smooth, I guess it's because the page update doesn't have to wait for all the `Text` to be assembled.

**However, spacing between `Text` and the line-spacing in a `Text`/`TextEditor` are different,  causing the problem of misalignment**

**I have tried to set `spacing` in the `VStack` or add `.padding` to each `Text`, but unfortunately, I found that the size that needs to be compensated is different on different devices.**

***Is there any way to speedup my `reduce` plan or solve the misalignment problem?***

You can reproduce `reduce` plan with the following code,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReduceView: View {
    @State var content = "x=1\n" + "y=x+1\n" + "x=1\n" + "y=x+1"
    @State var lines = [["x", "=", "1"], ["y", "=", "x", "+", "1"], ["x", "=", "1"], ["y", "=", "x", "+", "1"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                lines.reduce(Text("")) { text, line in text +
                    line.reduce(Text("")) { text, word in text + Text(word)
                    } + Text("\n")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .border(.orange)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
            .padding([.trailing, .leading], 5)
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    .background(.clear)
            } else {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .background(.clear)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReduceView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReduceView()
    }
}
```

The `ForEach` plan is shown here,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ForEachView: View {
    @State var content = "x=1\n" + "y=x+1\n" + "x=1\n" + "y=x+1"
    @State var lines = [["x", "=", "1"], ["y", "=", "x", "+", "1"], ["x", "=", "1"], ["y", "=", "x", "+", "1"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){//}, spacing: -0.5){
                ForEach(0..<lines.count, id:\.self){i in
                    lines[i].reduce(Text("")) { text, word in text + Text(word)
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .border(.orange)
                //.padding(.bottom, -0.5)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
            .padding([.trailing, .leading], 5)
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    .background(.clear)
            } else {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .background(.clear)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ForEachView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEachView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `.lineSpacing(...)` set it for your `TextView` and your `TextEditor` to the same value.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Thank you very much, but it doesn't work. I think that it is because `.lineSpacing(...)` only change the line spacing in one `TextEditor`/`TextView` but will not influence the spacing between `TextView` in a `VStack`.